# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbio.stats.diversity'

Tags: python, module, bioinformatics, skbio

I am trying to import the `beta_diversity` function from the skbio.stats.diversity module in Python:

```
from skbio.stats.diversity import beta_diversity
```

but I am encountering a ModuleNotFoundError with the message `No module named 'skbio.stats.diversity'`.

I have already installed the scikit-bio package using pip. I have checked my Python environment and confirmed that the package is installed. However, it seems that the specific module within scikit-bio is not accessible.

I have tried reinstalling the package and updating it to the latest version, but the error still persists.

Why am I  encountering this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diversity module is directly under `skbio`, your import statement should be:

```py
from skbio.diversity import beta_diversity
```